# Getting date intervals from vector

Tags: clojure

I have a day ordered vector in clojure that's something like

```
(def a [{:day #inst "2017-01-01T21:57:14.873-00:00" :balance 100.00},
        {:day #inst "2017-01-05T21:57:14.873-00:00" :balance -50.00},
        {:day #inst "2017-01-10T21:57:14.873-00:00" :balance -100.00},
        {:day #inst "2017-01-14T21:57:14.873-00:00" :balance 50.00},
        {:day #inst "2017-01-17T21:57:14.873-00:00" :balance -200.00}])
```

I would like to get all date intervals where balance is negative.  The
period ends when balance gets positive on next position or when
balance changes its value but keeps negative, like:

```
[{:start #inst "2017-01-05T21:57:14.873-00:00"
  :end #inst "2017-01-09T21:57:14.873-00:00"
  :value -50.00},
 {:start "2017-01-10T21:57:14.873-00:00"
  :end "2017-01-13T21:57:14.873-00:00"
  :value -100.00},
 {:start "2017-01-17T21:57:14.873-00:00"
  :value -200.00}]
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737578/complex-data-manipulation-in-clojure) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232718/date-periods-in-clojure) but I couldn't adapt to my data. How can I do it?

Comment: Try `partition-by` with a selector like `(comp neg? :balance)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheating a little with the dates by using this not yet implemented function, which is supposed to decrement a date:

```
(defn dec-date [d] d)
```

This would be one way to solve the problem:

```
(->> a
     (partition-by #(-> % :balance neg?))
     (drop-while #(-> % first :balance pos?))
     (mapcat identity)
     (map (juxt :day :balance))
     (partition 2 1)
     (map (fn [[[date-1 val-1] [date-2 val-2]]]
            (if (neg? val-1)
              {:start date-1
               :end   (dec-date date-2)
               :value val-1}
              {:start date-2
               :value val-1}))))) 

;;=> ({:start "05/01", :end "10/01", :value -50.0} {:start "10/01", :end "14/01", :value -100.0} {:start "17/01", :value 50.0})
```

If `dec-date` was properly implemented then the first `:end` would be "09/01" rather than "10/01" and the second `:end` would be "13/01" rather than "14/01", which would be the correct answer.

Now hopefully an improved answer that will work for more edge cases:

```
(->> a
     (partition-by #(-> % :balance neg?))
     (drop-while #(-> % first :balance pos?))
     (mapcat identity)
     (map (juxt :day :balance))
     (partition-all 2 1)
     (keep (fn [[[date-1 val-1] [date-2 val-2]]]
             (cond
               (neg? val-1) (cond-> {:start date-1
                                     :value val-1}
                                    date-2 (assoc :end (dec-date date-2)))
               (pos? val-1) nil
               :else {:start date-2
                      :value val-1}))))
```

Comment: Chris, it works for the example I gave but when I have a vector with only 2 positions `(def a [{:day #inst "2017-01-01T21:57:14.873-00:00" :balance 100.00}, {:day #inst "2017-01-05T21:57:14.873-00:00" :balance -50.00}])`, this code returns nothing :( how can I solve it?

Comment: The main thing that helped there was realising that `(partition 2` was leaving off the last value. The rest was just fixing up problems like `nil` coming through for the end date.

Comment: There will still be problems. For instance I can see that zero values are not being handled.